# HttpWebRequest over SSL, Cerificates, etc

Tags: ssl, httpwebrequest, x509certificate

Could you guys show me a simple example of HttpWebRequest over SSL with authorization on a form, 
for example - how to get through gmail authorization?

I can't find any normal example:
  - how to actually obtain a certificate?
  - how to pass credentials
  - and other stuff...

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Send email through GMAIL?

If so you should be able to use SmtpWebRequest for that.